# How can i get different data combined in flow in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine

I am developing an application.
There is one problem.

I have one screen that displays a list of topics.
I would like to display different data combined. One is the topic entity and the other is the number of times you thought about this topic.

But... I don't know... how can I get this?

I was thinking of one way, please check the code below.

```kotlin
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            topicRepository.getTopicList()
                .onStart {
                    _topicListUiState.value = TopicListUiState.Loading
                }
                .catch { exception ->
                    _topicListUiState.value = TopicListUiState.Failed(TAG_TOPIC_LIST_PRESENTER, exception.localizedMessage)
                }
                .collectLatest { topicList ->
                    topicList.forEach { topic ->
                        thinkRepository.getCountOfThinkListByTopicId(topic.id)
                            .collect { count ->
                                _topicListUiState.value = TopicListUiState.Success(topicList.map { it.toTopicListDTO(count.toInt()) })
                            }
                    }
                }
        }
```

I wonder if there is a better way.
Also, please give me advice on what field I should study more.

Thank you for reading!
Have a gooood and nice day!

---

There are three data classes TopicListDTO and Topic Entity, and Think Entity.
I'd like to show list of TopicListDTO, which combines Topic and Think.
I made that TopicListDTO was created just to display two things combined.

```kotlin
data class TopicListDTO(
    val id: Long,
    val topic: String,
    val countOfThink: Int = 0,
    val registDate: String,
    val updateDate: String
)

@Entity(tableName = "topics")
data class Topic(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Long = System.currentTimeMillis(),
    val topic: String,
    val registDate: String,
    val updateDate: String
) {
    fun toTopicListDTO(count: Int): TopicListDTO {
        return TopicListDTO(
            id = id,
            topic = topic,
            countOfThink = count,
            registDate = registDate,
            updateDate = updateDate
        )
    }
}

@Entity(
    tableName = "thinks",
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Topic::class,
            parentColumns = ["id"],
            childColumns = ["topicId"],
            onDelete = CASCADE,
            onUpdate = CASCADE
        )
    ]
)
data class Think(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Long = System.currentTimeMillis(),
    val topicId: Long,
    val think: String,
    val registDate: String,
    val updateDate: String
)
```

And after checking @TheLibrarian's advice, I tried SQL Query.
But I didn't ...

```
SELECT * FROM topics LEFT OUTER JOIN thinks on topics.id = thinks.topicId
```

Please check below picture, It's I want.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGz73.png)

Comment: Did you try using [merge](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/merge.html)?

Comment: While this seems doable in Kotlin, I think you could create SQL query that will do all that for you(Foreign key), and then you can just fetch it and map only once. I see that you have 2 repositories(topic and think). I think if you are fetching a Topic, it should come with think(did you mean thing?) included.

Comment: Does your current code even work correctly? If I read it correctly, you will load count only for the first topic and then assign this count to all topics. I just wanted to confirm I understand your case correctly.

Comment: And I agree with @TheLibrarian . Problem with the current code is that we need N + 1 flows to observe everything. It would make more sense to get everything in a single flow or at least have a flow that returns think counts for multiple topic ids.

Comment: please do not post screenshots of code

Comment: @Pawel oh, sorry .. I removed screenshots and add codeblocks!

Comment: @TheLibrarian omg, Thanks! I tried to SQL query but I didn't solve ... 
Think is just thinking. for each topic

Comment: @broot yeah correct. I only loaded think on the first topic.
I updated the question. Could you please check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed, those things can usually be fixed with a little bit more complex SQL Query.

This way emits from changes are handled on the `Room`s side and you don't have to handle them.

You were on the right track with the `LEFT JOIN` - the query would look something like this:

```
SELECT Topics.Id, Topics.Topic, Topics.RegistDate, COUNT(TopicId) AS topicCount
FROM Topics
LEFT JOIN Thinks ON Topics.Id=Thinks.TopicId
GROUP BY Topics.Id;
```

From Room 2.4 and higher, there is also **@MapInfo**(*MapColumn*)

```
@Query("
SELECT Topics.Id, Topics.Topic, COUNT(TopicId) AS countOfThink, Topics.RegistDate, Topics.UpdateDate
FROM Topics
LEFT JOIN Thinks ON Topics.Id=Thinks.TopicId
GROUP BY Topics.Id
")
fun getTopics(): Map<Topic, @MapColumn(columnName = "countOfThink") Integer>
```

Now, *I am not completely sure* but I think you can directly return the result as `TopicListDTO` - but make sure the column names match with variable names - `@ColumnInfo` should also fix this possible issue

```
data class TopicListDTO(
    val id: Long,
    val topic: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name="countOfThink")
    val countOfThink: Int,
    val registDate: String,
    val updateDate: String
)

suspend fun getTopics(): List<TopicListDTO>
```

Comment: Omg. .... Fortunately, I'm using Room version 2.4.3, so I'll have to try again as you said.
I got the data I wanted... omg... thank you...
I got the data with TopicListDTO using @ColumnInfo. Thank you for leaving a comment. have a goooooood day!